# OpenShift deploy java configured web project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, openshift

I try to deploy webproject which do not have `web.xml` and `WEB-INF`, and fully configured using spring mvc java configuration. `.war` file works perfectly on local machine in tomcat 7. But when I put war on the openshift application using winscp and then trying to connect to it, I get throws 404 notfaund response. Maybe someone can explain me what can be wrong. Also I use `html` not `jsp` for web content.

1. Should I install additionaly java to application?
2. Should projects be always configured with web.xml?

Comment: I solved by adding `web.xml` file, for `openShift` cannot be fully javaConfig. So I made 50/50 config, using this doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/developing-web-applications.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either deploy war or can add project folder like:
$TOMCAT_HOM/your-project-directory/*.html,*.jsp/WEB-INF/class (all java files) and WEB-INF/lib (your all jars) + WEB-INF/web.xml

1. make sure java is installed and all variable sets on the system
2. you must add all your java files in web.xml

Comment: Thank you for advice. Problem was in JavaConfiguration. It Cannot be fully java configured, there is required web.xml.